# Build error plv8 - using the make command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, plv8

### After downloading source code by executing commands:

```
$ wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v3.0.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf v3.0.0.tar.gz
$ cd plv8-3.0.0
$ make
```

### Getting an error after running the `make` command

```
mkdir -p build
cd build; git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
Cloning into 'depot_tools'...
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3/3)
remote: Total 54431 (delta 36356), reused 54431 (delta 36356)
Receiving objects: 100% (54431/54431), 49.54 MiB | 2.76 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36356/36356), done.
cd build; fetch v8; cd v8; git checkout 8.6.405; gclient sync ; cd build/config ; cd ../.. ; tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release -- use_custom_libcxx=false v8_monolithic=true v8_use_external_startup_data=false is_component_build=false is_debug=true v8_enable_i18n_support=false
Running: gclient root
WARNING: Your metrics.cfg file was invalid or nonexistent. A new one will be created.
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "v8",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Updating depot_tools...
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
Updating depot_tools...

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/_gclient_v8_vbww190s' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build'
Cloning into '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/_gclient_v8_vbww190s'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Operation timed outMiB/s
error: 6198 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
WARNING: subprocess '"git" "-c" "core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g" "clone" "--no-checkout" "--progress" "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git" "/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/_gclient_v8_vbww190s"' in /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build failed; will retry after a short nap...

________ running 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/_gclient_v8_vbww190s' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build' attempt 2 / 2
Cloning into '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/_gclient_v8_vbww190s'...
remote: Total 1026913 (delta 838139), reused 1026913 (delta 838139)
Receiving objects: 100% (1026913/1026913), 1008.17 MiB | 11.51 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (838139/838139), done.
Syncing projects: 100% (29/29), done.

________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth --bucket chromium-browser-clang -s tools/clang/dsymutil/bin/dsymutil.arm64.sha1 -o tools/clang/dsymutil/bin/dsymutil' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
0> Downloading tools/clang/dsymutil/bin/dsymutil@331b57be925505b807f106497ded16317dc6efdf...
Downloading 1 files took 221.082646 second(s)
Hook 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth --bucket chromium-browser-clang -s tools/clang/dsymutil/bin/dsymutil.arm64.sha1 -o tools/clang/dsymutil/bin/dsymutil' took 221.26 secs
Running hooks:  24% ( 8/33) clang_format_mac_arm64
________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth --bucket chromium-clang-format -s buildtools/mac/clang-format.arm64.sha1 -o buildtools/mac/clang-format' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
0> Downloading buildtools/mac/clang-format@5553d7a3d912b7d49381ad68c9a56740601a57a0...
Downloading 1 files took 7.090771 second(s)
Running hooks:  36% (12/33) wasm_spec_tests
________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz.sha1' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
0> Downloading test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz@635d01fb7ef81b8bb8155c1f1f095ac3a2617ced...
0> Extracting 655 entries from test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz to test/wasm-spec-tests/tests
Downloading 1 files took 12.596956 second(s)
Hook 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-spec-tests/tests.tar.gz.sha1' took 12.65 secs
Running hooks:  39% (13/33) wasm_js
________ running 'python3 third_party/depot_tools/download_from_google_storage.py --no_resume --no_auth -u --bucket v8-wasm-spec-tests -s test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz.sha1' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
0> Downloading test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz@5c21ce799496f0b0972d1b9eda9cbe0754776776...
0> Extracting 258 entries from test/wasm-js/tests.tar.gz to test/wasm-js/tests
Downloading 1 files took 5.062450 second(s)
Running hooks:  66% (22/33) mac_toolchain
________ running 'python3 build/mac_toolchain.py' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
Skipping Mac toolchain installation for mac
Running hooks:  69% (23/33) clang
________ running 'python3 tools/clang/scripts/update.py' in '/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build/v8'
Downloading https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-clang/Mac_arm64/clang-llvmorg-17-init-16420-g0c545a44-1.tar.xz .......... Done.
Hook 'vpython3 -vpython-spec .vpython3 -vpython-tool install' took 17.29 secs
Running hooks: 100% (33/33), done.
Running: git submodule foreach 'git config -f $toplevel/.git/config submodule.$name.ignore all'
Running: git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
Running: git config diff.ignoreSubmodules all
Updating files: 100% (8833/8833), done.
Previous HEAD position was 5b934b91d84 [wasm][turboshaft] Int64Lowering: Support addition
HEAD is now at b0baada2f1c Version 8.6.405
Updating depot_tools...
Syncing projects: 100% (29/29), done.

WARNING: 'v8/third_party/abseil-cpp' is no longer part of this client.
It is recommended that you manually remove it or use 'gclient sync -D' next time.

WARNING: 'v8/third_party/clang-format/script' is no longer part of this client.
It is recommended that you manually remove it or use 'gclient sync -D' next time.

WARNING: 'v8/third_party/google_benchmark/src' is no longer part of this client.
It is recommended that you manually remove it or use 'gclient sync -D' next time.

WARNING: 'v8/third_party/logdog/logdog' is no longer part of this client.
It is recommended that you manually remove it or use 'gclient sync -D' next time.

________ running 'cipd ensure -log-level error -root /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build -ensure-file /var/folders/kn/b8b9x9yn683cjfkl1xd9jjwh0000gn/T/tmp4_v6_qf9.ensure' in '.'
Errors:
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/isolate/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 11): no such tag
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/isolated/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 12): no such tag
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/swarming/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 13): no such tag
Error: Command 'cipd ensure -log-level error -root /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.0.0/build -ensure-file /var/folders/kn/b8b9x9yn683cjfkl1xd9jjwh0000gn/T/tmp4_v6_qf9.ensure' returned non-zero exit status 1
Errors:
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/isolate/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 11): no such tag
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/isolated/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 12): no such tag
  failed to resolve infra/tools/luci/swarming/mac-arm64@git_revision:b022173f8069cf8001d4cf2a87ce7c5f0eae220f (line 13): no such tag

env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/v8] Error 127
```

#### fixed this issue

v8 (and thus plv8) did not support arm64 on macOS at that point. you should be using at least 3.1, and likely the most recent release of 3.1.7.

see https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/r3.1/Changes#L34 for when arm64 support started.

#### Run:

```
$ wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v3.1.7.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf v3.1.7.tar.gz
$ cd plv8-3.1.7
$ make
```

#### Got this new error after running `make` command:

```
make -f Makefiles/Makefile.macos v8
Setting up build directory
Downloading gn source
Building gn
ninja: Entering directory `out/'
[194/194] LINK gn
Downloading v8 source
Patching v8
error: can't open patch '../../patches/*.patch': No such file or directory
Downloading up third party sources
Building v8
ERROR at //build/config/mac/mac_sdk.gni:92:19: Script returned non-zero exit code.
_mac_sdk_result = exec_script(script_name, sdk_info_args, "scope")
                  ^----------
Current dir: /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.1.7/build/v8/out.gn/
Command: python3 /Users/spartacus/plv8-3.1.7/build/v8/build/config/apple/sdk_info.py macosx
Returned 1.
stderr:

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.1.7/build/v8/build/config/apple/sdk_info.py", line 167, in <module>
    FillXcodeVersion(settings, args.developer_dir)
  File "/Users/spartacus/plv8-3.1.7/build/v8/build/config/apple/sdk_info.py", line 80, in FillXcodeVersion
    lines = subprocess.check_output(['xcodebuild',
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 465, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 569, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['xcodebuild', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

See //build/toolchain/mac/BUILD.gn:5:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/mac/mac_sdk.gni")
^--------------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:1510:1: which caused the file to be included.
action("postmortem-metadata") {
^------------------------------
make[1]: *** [build/v8] Error 1
make: *** [v8] Error 2
```